# how do i upload a video and image to my server with php script

Tags: php, asp-classic

I want my client to be able to upload images from the back end into the server. Please help me out. and also i need a php script to upload videos too. Thank you, here is my code and it is not working

```
<?php

// Configuration - Your Options
  $allowed_filetypes = array(

'.doc',

'.docx',

'.xls',

'.csv',

);  


  # array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.doc'); 

  // These will be the types of file that will pass the validation.
  $max_filesize = 1048567; // Maximum filesize in BYTES (currently 0.5MB).
  $upload_path = './files/'; // The place the files will be uploaded to (currently a 'files' directory).

 $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).
 $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); // Get the extension from the filename.

 // Check if the filetype is allowed, if not DIE and inform the user.
 if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
  die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

 // Now check the filesize, if it is too large then DIE and inform the user.
 if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
  die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

 // Check if we can upload to the specified path, if not DIE and inform the user.
 if(!is_writable($upload_path))
  die('You cannot upload to the specified directory.');

// change the name of the file  
$docid = substr(md5(uniqid()),30);

 // Upload the file to your specified path.
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $docid.$ext))
     echo 'Your file upload was successful, Thank you'; // It worked.
  else
     echo 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.'; // It failed :(.

?>
```

Comment: What error message do you get when trying to upload a file? Try enabling `error_reporting` at the top of your php file.

Comment: Does your html form "multipart form data" encoded?

Comment: Yes, my html form support "multipart form data"

Comment: @ Krister Andersson; 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.' that is d error i get when uploding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to increase time limit for video uploading in php.ini file

```
max_execution_time = 3000 // 3000 or your requirements
```

And add the allowed type in array list

```
 $allowed_filetypes =
  array('.doc','.docx','.xls','.csv','.flv');
```

Comment: I don't think this must be the reason why the file isn't uploaded. It could be a number of things like: folder permissions, file extensions, no enctype in the form etc.

Comment: Please what do you mean by "no enctype in the form"

Comment: I already know about file extension and the right folder has been specified in the code above